# About number of NFSTs

Tags: automata, finite-automata, combinatorics, transducers

Can we proof the number of NFSTs with $n$ states : $n.2^{mpn}.2^{n}$ where $p$ is the cardinal of input alphabet and $m$ the cardinal of output alphabet.

Comment: What is the the output alphabet? There is no concept of "output alphabet" in the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#Formal_definition) of a NFA.

Comment: Sorry, i mean Non deterministic finite state transducers.